# Reset domain name redirect for a digitalocean droplet

Tags: digital-ocean

I used to have a domain for my digitalocean droplet. The domain expired. When I type my droplet IP address it redirect to that expired domain and gives an error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.
I removed all of the domain records in digitalocean for my droplet.
How can I prevent this redirect from happening and get access to my droplet via IP?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a redirect in the Apache or nginx config on the droplet to forward to your former domain name? or check .htaccess files in the configured web root folder

Comment: Also thought it was the case, but for some reason it's not:(
Can the redirect be somewhere else?